# Algo for finding power i.e. n^p

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

An algorithm for finding **n^p** is:

```
unsigned long long power(unsigned n, unsigned p)
{
    unsigned long long x=1, y=n;
    while(p > 0)
    {
        if(p&1) x *= y;
        y *= y;
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Can somebody explain the logic/math behind this algorithm. I know it works and worked it out for a few test cases (dry run). I mean how does it work and how is this efficient from the general naive method.

Comment: This is O(log n) compared to O(n) of naive method. It will halves the exponent in every iteration.

Comment: IITian asking a question, then it must be difficult :p

Comment: Why don't you printf x, y & p, per iteration? That will easily help you understand. This code basically would find iterate through the individual bits of p, instead of running loop for i=0 to p.

Comment: Gopi you should try printing each variable in the loop, then you will know how shift operator with 1 bit is changed...and the resultant is formed in x.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya had visualized that already.

anyways thanks, got it; I see it was silly of me.

Comment: btw, +1 for the algorithm... I was not aware of this algo. Seems easy after reading it :-)

Comment: @anishsane: yup, after a bit of googling on this, I came to know that this is the standard method for doing modular exponentiation for huge numbers in asymmetric cryptography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*exponentiation by squaring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring): the `>>= 1` is a fancy way to write `/= 2`.

The idea behind it is that if `p` is even, you can take `n^(p/2)` and square it; when `p` is odd, `p-1` must be even, so you can take `n^((p-1)/2)`, square it, and then multiply the result by `n` to compensate for the `1` that you subtracted from `p` before squaring.

Comment: Yep, I know its `/=2` and that `(p&1)` checks if its odd, but I wanted to know the logic behind it and its complexity

Comment: thanks for the link btw, going thru it